# Why C++ new is not returning pointer to the object it creates?

Tags: c++, oop

I was understanding the following code, as per my knowledge when I declare an object using new, it constructs an object of particular type and returns the pointer to that object. But here when I create a student object using new it does not returning pointer to that object. Also, when I am calling **new student(s1)** "**student(student* s)**" is called instead of giving error like no type conversion from student to student*

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class student {
    public:
        int cool;

        student(student* s){ // this constructor is taking pointer to s whereas i am calling it by value below
            this->cool=s->cool;
        }
        student(){
            this->cool=1;
        }
};
void blah(student s){
    printf("cool:%d\n",s.cool);
}

int main(){

    student s1=new student(); // here new is not returning student*
    s1.cool=2;
    student s2=new student(s1); // here we are passing s1 which of type student but constructor (student*) is called why ???
    blah(s2);
}
```

Following is output I am getting without any error:

> cool:2

Comment: Why would you expect a var of type 'student' to hold a type of 'student*'?   You get no errors or warnings??

Comment: @MartinJames It's using the implicit conversion constructor `student::student(student*)`.

Comment: Oh my.. where are the pointers *s1 and *s2 ;)

Comment: what is the reason for the down vote?

Comment: @UmutTabak I'm guessing because this seems like an issue of not understanding basic C++ syntax for pointers (`student s1=new student();`)

Comment: @crashmstr I don't think so; it seems like OP knows something is wrong because it sounds like he expects a compile-time error but is surprised that it compiles and appears to work. It seems he just isn't aware that one-arg constructors not marked `explicit` are used to convert a mismatched type where possible -- a case of two wrongs making an (almost-)right.

Answer (score 7):

You are leaking memory.

This constructor:

```
student(student* s)
```

Is used to satisfy conversions implicitly, because it is not marked `explicit`.  So what happens here:

```
student s1=new student();
```

Is that you heap-allocate a new `student` object.  The `new` expression evaluates to a pointer.  When the compiler looks at the assignment it knows that the assignment won't work, because `s1` is a `student` and you are assigning a `student *` to it.  So it looks around for a way to convert it and finds the constructor I mentioned above.

So what you are doing is equivalent to:

```
student s1 = student(new student());
```

Since you never `delete` the pointer, the heap allocation is leaked, but otherwise your program performs correctly, from your perspective.

If you mark the conversion constructor as follows:

```
explicit student(student* s)
```

Then the compiler will not automatically use this constructor for conversions, requiring explicit invocation of some sort, and the line `student s1=new student();` will indeed cause a compile-time error, while allowing `student s1 = student(new student());` to work (but of course it would still cause a memory leak).

Answer (score 2):

`new` is returning a pointer to a `student`. Of course it is!

What is happening in the first case is that the line `student s1 = new student()` is calling the `student(student*)` constructor to construct `s1`.

In the second case, the line `student s2 = new student(s1)` is first calling the default copy constructor and then calling the `student(student*)` constructor to construct `s2`.

In both cases, there will be a memory leak because you're not calling `delete` to match your `new`s.

This kind of behaviour is why it is a very good idea to use `explicit` before single parameter constructors unless you actually want this kind of implicit conversion (and, even if you think you do, you probably don't).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got the weird idea that `new` does not return a pointer. The code you posted does not in any way support that claim. This initialization

```
student s1 = new student();
```

creates a *default-constructed* `student` object with `new`. The pointer returned by `new` is then passed to the `student::student(student *)` constructor, as it should be.

The second initialization

```
student s2 = new student(s1);
```

creates a *copy-constructed* `student` object with `new`. The pointer returned by `new` is then passed to the `student::student(student *)` constructor, as it should be.

Why did you expect a "no type conversion from `student` to `student *`" error in the second case is not clear. Your `student` class has an implicit copy-constructor declared and defined by the compiler. This is the constructor used in `student(s1)` initialization. There's no need for any `student` to `student *` conversion here and no error.

In both cases the `student::student(student *)` is called with a pointer returned by `new`. It appears that you for some reason believe that in the first case `student::student(student *)` is not called. But it is a completely unfounded belief. It is called.